# SQL Propper indexing, range + normal search at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, indexing

Suppose I have simple table like this:

```
ID (PRIMARY)
time (INT)
stage (TINYINT)
other fields...
```

I have to do **range search on time** while **normally selecting stage**. With SQL query example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time>10000 AND (stage=1 OR stage=3 OR stage=4)
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:** There are **a lot** of rows with **stage = 2**, let's say 99% of the table. There are only **5 distinct stage values.**

What would be the propper indexing of this table?

Comment: If it makes a difference, in this table `COUNT(DISTINCT stage) <= 5` holds. So, in theory, five separate indexes on time would suffice.

Comment: I would think that only `(stage, time)` or just `(time)` index would be useful here. I doubt that `(time, stage)` index can be helpful for such query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the distribution of the values in the different columns.
If you have very few possible `stage` values you will probably have the best performance with either a separate index on `time` and one on `stage` or with a combined index `time, stage`.

But if you have lots of distinct `stage` values it might be faster to order the index the other way around: `stage, time`.

But using `OR` makes the `stage` search more fragmented compared to an `AND` search. Therefore I would try to have `time` first in the index.

The only way to know for sure on your specific set of data is to try and measure, but above three mentioned candidates are my top candidates for indexes.

**Edit**
You might want to create a clustered index on `time`, possibly `time, stage` if most of your queries search by time range. This way you minimize lookup in the table once you found the correct rows in the index.
Beware that this can create a fragmented dataspace if `time` is strictly increasing when you insert new records.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. Does answer change in any way?

Comment: I don't see any obvious changes. This should be really fast if you don't have insane amounts of data. I added a note about clustered indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index with time first and stage second if there's a low cardinality in the stage-column. You can also change the stage part to `AND stage IN (2, 10)` might improve performance as well as readability. :)

Good luck!